# For which $\alpha$ is $\int_Q \frac{1}{(x^2+2y^2)^{\alpha}}dxdy$ finite, where $Q=[0,1]\times[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Determine for which $\alpha$ the following integral is finite:
>   $$\int_Q \frac{1}{(x^2+2y^2)^{\alpha}}dxdy \qquad Q=[0,1]\times[0,1]$$

I don't actually know what is the most efficient way to proceed. It's clear that the only problem is in the origin so we just need to describe what happens in a neighbourhood of it.
I have now different ideas in mind: I can maybe try to do it in polar coordinates, but I think it really makes the task more difficult. Should I use Taylor formulas? 
What is the most intuitive and efficient way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the region $P$ as $$P=\{(x,y)\ \ |\ \ x>0 \ \ ,\ \ y>0\quad,\quad x^2+y^2<4\}\supset Q$$

Hence the integral can be bounded above by $$\iint_Q {dxdy\over (x^2+2y^2)}{<\iint_P {dxdy\over (x^2+2y^2)^\alpha}
\\=\int_0^2\int_0^{\pi\over 2} r^{1-2\alpha}{1\over (1+\sin^2\phi)^\alpha}drd\phi
\\=\left[\int_0^2 r^{1-2\alpha}dr\right]\left[\int_0^{\pi\over 2}{1\over (1+\sin^2\phi)^\alpha}d\phi\right]
}$$The integral $\left[\int_0^{\pi\over 2}{1\over (1+\sin^2\phi)^\alpha}d\phi\right]$ is positive and bounded and the integral $\left[\int_0^1 r^{1-2\alpha}dr\right]$ becomes bounded if $\alpha< 1$ and unbounded if $\alpha\ge1$ by choosing $$P=\{(x,y)\ \ |\ \ x>0 \ \ ,\ \ y>0\quad,\quad x^2+y^2<1\}\subset Q$$

Comment: For $\alpha=1$ we have $\int_0^1 r^{1-2\alpha}$ diverges..

Comment: Sorry for that. A typo that fixed.

Comment: By the way, thanks. Is this a standard procedure? Like, if I have to discuss convergence about integrals, I have to close my set inside a bigger one?

Comment: Actually, choose your set more regular such that you can calculate the integral over that set, fully or partially. The set may be smaller or larger than the original one based on whether the upper or lower bound is desired, as well as the importance of the function behavior in the new set. For example, in this case converting to polar coordinates is beneficial since the integral can be partially solved, so it is better to convert the region to one with polar symmetry.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great help.

Comment: Your welcome. Good luck!